# Getting huge Firebase access token

Tags: java, android, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm using Firebase authentication together with Cloud Endpoints Frameworks.
In context of this, I have two questions which belong together:

In my Android app I'm requesting the access token after a successfully login in the following way:

```
FirebaseUser user = mFirebaseAuthenticator.getCurrentUser();

user.getIdToken(true).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<GetTokenResult>() {
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<GetTokenResult> task) {
    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
      mIDToken = task.getResult().getToken();
      Log.d("attempLogin", "GetTokenResult result = " + mIDToken);
    } else {
      Log.d("attempLogin", "Cannot get token = " + task.getException());
    }
  }
 });
```

Afterwards I pass the received access token to the automatically generated 
endpoints framework client API method **allOrdersRequest(...)**

```
OrderCollection orders = allOrdersRequest.setOauthToken(mIDToken).execute();
```

to execute a valid and authorized backend API call.

1st question: 
The received access token has about 800 characters, which is in my opinion 
relatively too much. It's almost 1kb which has to be send with each backend API method request. Is my assumption correct, or should (or even can I) change the access token size in Firebase's console?

2nd question:
Is it the right way to pass the received token to the **setOauthToken()** method of the endpoints framework client API to perform an authorized API request, or must I manipulate each time the httpheader of the **allOrdersRequest()**?

Comment: @all Does nobody have a clue? I'm sure, I'm not the only user of firebase authentication and a cloud endpoints framework clients...Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I found the correct way to authorize a cloud endpoints API request:

Using the method **setOauthToken()** from one of my generated cloud endpoints **client** API requests (in this example the method **allOrdersRequest()** is a backend api method) is the wrong way.
Instead, it is neccessary to specify the "Authorization" http header field of typ **bearer** and assign to it the requested Firebase access token (idToken) in the REST API request (endpoints client API)

Here is an example:

// Initiate cloud endpoints client API builder
Endpoint.Builder endpoint = new Endpoint.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new GsonFactory(), null);
        endpoint.setRootUrl("https://my_project_id.appspot.com/_ah/api/");
        endpoint.setApplicationName("my_project_id");

```
    Endpoint service = endpoint.build();
    HttpHeaders authorizationHeader = new HttpHeaders();
    authorizationHeader.setAuthorization("Bearer " + mAccessToken);

    // Model instance
    OrderRequest orderRequest = new OrderRequest();
    orderRequest.setBagId(35);
    orderRequest.setPriority(9);

    orderRequest.setCustomer("foo@bar.com");
    try {
        Endpoint.ProcesOrderRequest request = service.procesOrderRequest(orderRequest);
        request.setRequestHeaders(authorizationHeader);
        Order order = request.execute();
        Log.d("ExecuteAPIRequest", "OrderId result = " + order.getOrderId());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Exception caught: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: NB IdToken is not the same as AccessToken. The AccessToken is much smaller. You should be sending it.